# USB Devices randomly disconnects and connects windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb

I've this weird problem where my mouse and external HDD, when plugged in to either USB 2.0 or 3.0 port, randomly disconnects and connects after a few seconds. I am unable to find a pattern to the problems that are occuring.

So far, I've Googled quite a bit and found no solution that worked for me. I have tried to remove and install the drivers of both the mouse and the external HDD. I have also changed `USB selective suspend setting` to `disabled` and this did not work.

Thinking it might have been an issue with power supply (even though it has always been working before), I have removed any USB devices and plugged just in a single device at a time, the problem is still occuring. I have also bend the tabs on the ports so they perfectly fit my USB devices, still not working as intended.

My laptop is running Windows 10, it only occured after using Windows 10 (used Windows 8.1 before this, no issues). However the problem didn't occur immediately after installing Windows 10, so I am not sure if this is related as other people have the same issue with Windows 7 and 8.x.

By the way, I have also tried to change `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` on my USB devices to `false`, did not work either. **Also, I just found out, when my mouse disconnects it is still receiving power as the LED indicators stay on.**

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: Also, I just found out, when my mouse disconnects it is still received power as the LED indicators stay on.

Answer (score 1):

Check the energy profile on your system, maybe you have enabled on your pc to save battery or power.

**Updated**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however my power options are all set to high performance and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Any third party software managing your system energy? Some manufacters like lenovo has it.

Comment: Check for the individual turning off from windows. I just updated my post, hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure, I'm on an Acer so power supply has always been, iffy :p And I checked to make sure, but I already removed that option.